# limit of convergent sequence of contractions is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ that (pointwise) converges to a function $f$. Suppose that all $f_n$ are contractions, prove that $f$ is a contraction as well.

Here's what I have:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
| f(x) - f(y) |
&= | \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(y) |\\
&= | \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(f_n(x) - f_n(y)) |\\
&=  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|f_n(x) - f_n(y) |\\
&< \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|x-y|
&= |x-y|
\end{array}
$$

That's a bunch of symbols.
I fear that I might have waved my hands too much at the details.
I can't point to any theorems that tell my that I'm alowed to proceed with the third equality.

Is this correct and why? Also, why does it matter that the $f_n$ are defined as $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$?

(The part of the question is: "prove that the convergence is uniform")

Comment: Haven't you missed to include a Lipschitz constant $k<1$ in the definition of contraction? In that case the constants can be different for each $f_n$ and might converge to $1$. Then the conclusion does not hold. Perhaps you have a different definition of contraction than I'm used to.The one I'm used to is the same as stated on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping

Comment: I'm using this one: (It seems equivalent) A function $f$ is a contraction if this holds: $\forall x,y : |f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y|$

Comment: They're not equivalent. According to the definition on Wikipedia the function $f(x) = x$ is not a contraction. According to your definition no function is a contraction (let $x=y$). If you add $x \neq y$ to your definition they are still not equivalent since the definition on Wikipedia says you have to stay away by some fixed distance from $|x-y|$ while your (modified) definition allows this distance to depend on $x, y$ and become arbitrarily small.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake, the definition in our notes is $\forall x,y:\ |f(x)-f(y)| \le |x-y|$ (so $\le$ instead of $<$).
Also the notes define a *strict* contraction as $\exists c\in [0,1[, \forall x,y:\ |f(x)-f(y)| \le c|x-y|$

Comment: Ok, you're all good then. The terminology I'm used to is to call it non-expansion and contraction instead of contraction and strict contraction.

Comment: Thank you very much for challenging me on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap $|\cdot|$ and $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$ because $|\cdot|$ is a continuous function. But when you take the limit, $<$ becomes $\leq$. It is not essential that the functions are from $[0,1]$ to itself here - however, fixed point theorems are stated with $[0,1]$ at first for simplicity. You can look at [Brouwer's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#Statement), [Banach's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Statement) fixed point theorems, etc.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you saying the proof is correct? (If I add the necessary explanation?)

Comment: Yes, although I would have stated it like this: $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|< |x-y|,~\forall\,n \implies \lim_{n \to +\infty}|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq |x-y| \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|.$$